# Boostrap - Border padding too wide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to complete a project as an exercise using bootstrap. The page I have to recreate is here: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/NNvBQW

I'm stuck at putting a border around the image. Here's my code:
https://codepen.io/krassheit/pen/mxmdWG?editors=1100

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="mainbox">
     <div class="col-xl">
       <h1 class="text-center">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
       <h2 class="text-center"><em>The man who saved a billion lives</em></h2>
       <div id="test">
       </div>
       <figure class="figure mx-auto d-block image-box">      
          <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Placeholder">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center"> Dr. Norman Borlaug, third from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</figcaption>
       </figure>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {background-color: gray;}

#mainbox {
  background-color: #eed2ee;  
}

.image-box{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

However I get the issue of the border expanding all the way to the margins of the main outer frame when the window I view it in is too wide. Only when I resize the window to be smaller than the native picture size the borders get resized to the actual padding. See attached screenshots:

[Wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B1SG.jpg)
[Narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtlOk.jpg)

Comment: you can simply give image width 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the class .image-box is `display:block;` , that means the div of that class is full-width, so when you view on the wide screen, that class will expand to full-width base on the resolution of that screen.

The solution is very simple, you just need to set .imade-box to `display:inline-block;` and it works !
When you have set it to inline-block, your image will not be centered anymore, so my next solution is set the parent div to `text-align:center`, and that is all you need ! :)

Check this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqQZoe?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Drop the figure element just use

```
<div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg">
</div>
```

The padding should be on the outer element (outside `#mainbox`, inside `.container`). You might want to check `.jumbotron` since that is what gets used in the example page...

You could go with `<figure>`, but using the `.mx-auto` class will have no effect unless the parent element is using `flexbox` (can be activated by `.d-flex`)

Check out [`.img-thumbnail`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#image-thumbnails) in the Bootstrap docs. That is what you need isn't it? :)

Comment: padding wil make the space for the image smaller. In case you want to create a (double) border on the image you should add padding to the image as you did to (unless using bootstrap styles). In case you don't know, you can click the 'change view' button of the example page to see how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the padding shouold be on the outer element? Could you explain?

I've rewritten the code using the thumbnail class, but it still looks the same. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="mainbox">
     <div class="col-xl">
       <h1 class="text-center">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
       <h2 class="text-center"><em>The man who saved a billion lives</em></h2>
       <div class="thumbnail image-box">
          <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" alt="Placeholder" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
          <p class="text-center">Dr. Norman Borlaug, third from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</p>
       </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I explicitly don't want to use the jumbotron class since I thought there should be a basic way to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer yourself (might not yet be possible because of low rating, but just so you know)

Comment: Yeah ... Bootstrap has some classes that you could build yourself, but why re-invent the wheel ;) If Bootstrap is included, you should use it, else just don't include Bootstrap... and do all the work yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem seems to be because you didn't assign left and right padding to the outer div. Try this html code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="mainbox">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl">
                <h1 class="text-center">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
                <h2 class="text-center"><em>The man who saved a billion lives</em></h2>
                <div class="thumbnail image-box">
                    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" alt="Placeholder" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
                    <p class="text-center">Dr. Norman Borlaug, third from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this css code

```
body {background-color: gray;}
    #mainbox {
      background-color: #eed2ee;
      padding: 30px 60px;
    }
    .image-box{
      background-color: red;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    .image-box img {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### Try to apply the border-style

you can use this style directly to the image class ".img-fluid"

```
.img-fluid{
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Or first try to have the figure section a width same as the image and apply the style to the figure section and you will get the same effect as you apply to the image.

Comment: The OP is looking for the padded (white) border, like with `.img-thumbnail`, not the real border ...